# Server configuration for Vue.js History Mode with Vercel?

Tags: json, vue.js, configuration, vercel

I set up a very basic Vue.js app essentially using [these steps](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login). When I added the router to this project, it asked whether I wanted to use History Mode and I said yes.

Now I am trying to implement the corresponding [server configuration changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) aka "add[ing] a simple catch-all fallback route to [the] server" but I'm not sure how to do this since I'm using [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs) for my deployments and from my understanding it's managing the server for me.

It seems like I'm able to do some configuration in Vercel, and I'm thinking maybe I need to configure a [redirect](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects) like in their firebase.json example? If so, would my vercel.json just look like this?

```
{
"redirects": [
    { "source": "**", "destination": "/index.html" }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Vercel automatically detects your configuration and sets it up so that all traffic points at your `index.html` file. That's kind of their big selling point.

If you want more explicit control, you could use the configuration shown in the **Caveat** section of the Vue docs you first linked to. Just create a simple component that redirects to the homepage and point `*` to it.

```js
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '*', component: NotFound }
  ]
})
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'NotFound',
  template: `<div></div>`,
  mounted() {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As per [Vercel's vercel.json routes upgrade guide](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#project-configuration/routes/upgrading), **SPA Fallback** section, use this on your vercel.json file:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

In my case I'm also using Vercel Serverless functions, so I also need rewrites for the /api routes, and here the order is important, it must be done this way:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" },
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, Vercel manages the server for you and you can configure vercel through a `vercel.json` file. In that `vercel.json` file you can define rewrite rules as you already assumed. The correct format for this is shown [here in the docs of vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites).

Since you want to add a match all rule which directs to the base of your path, adding the following to your `vercel.json` should work:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/:path*", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

#### Explanatory extras:

The `:path` basically symbolizes a placeholder and the `*` makes sure it doesn't just match one subpath deep but everything that follows after the initial slash.

For example without the `*` after `/:path` you would match `domain.xyz/foo` but not `domain.xyz/foo/bar`.

Furthermore since it's a named placeholder you can reuse the matched path for the destination like so `"destination": "/index.html/:path"`.

Which shouldn't be necessary for a frontend application like vue which uses the route inside the browser, but could be helpful for serverless functions.