# Proxy is not working in Vite js project and request is not getting redirected to the proper api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, vite, mern

I have a basic MERN stack application which I have deployed using vercel. 
The frontend is at "https://ticketify-silk.vercel.app/". 
The backend is at "https://ticketify-api.vercel.app/".

---

In the frontend code, I have used vite and also proxy to fetch data from api. Following is the code in the vite config file.

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'https://ticketify-api.vercel.app',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
        }
      },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

In the backend code as well, I have defined the following code to avoid the CORS error.

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://ticketify-silk.vercel.app"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "UPDATE"],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);
```

When I send a request from the frontend, instead of going to "https://ticketify-api.vercel.app/" it is going to "https://ticketify-silk.vercel.app/". This is the error that I am getting ->

[image]

So basically, the proxy is not working. And everything is running fine in my local environment, where the frontend is at "http://localhost:5173" and backend is at "http://localhost:8080".

Could anyone please suggest a solution? I already tried [proxy api is not working in Vite + Vue 3 project when it's deployed to Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73267938), but the solutions did not work for me. Can the issue be solved by any changes to the vercel.json file? I am not sure about it because I am deploying using vercel for the first time.

Comment: `Can the issue be solved by any changes to the vercel.json file?` isn't that exactly what the answer you linked to states? Which you said you "tried"? Perhaps you *did something wrong™* when you tried?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, and I also said that none of the solutions worked! Also, there are no upvotes on that solution, so I don't think it worked for anyone else either, or no one saw it.

Comment: Fair enough, can you show what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the server conf look like this:

```bash
server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'your target url'
    }
  },
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, basically, you proxy config are only valid on dev server , when you build/preview your app this proxy are no longer available to your app, it's explicitly defined on vite's [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy) (*"Configure custom proxy rules **for the dev server.**"*).

So what you want to do is to ensure that this "proxy" is also present on your vercel environment, I could achieve this by adding a vercel.json file under your project's root with the following content:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "destination": "https://your-api.domain/$1"
        },
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can read more on [vercel's docs](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/rewrites).

This worked for me, now any requests to `my-app.domain/api` are being rewritten to `my-api.domain/`. What I'm testing now is how to make this "https://your-api.domain" dynamic by passing an env variable to `vercel.json`, I'll let you know of any updates on this.

Answer (score 0):

i had to create this file : Vercel.json:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
      {
          "source": "/api/:path(.*)",
          "destination": "https://your-backendUrl/api/:path"
      },
      {
          "source": "/(.*)",
          "destination": "/"
      }
  ]
}
```